# CFBundleShortVersion must be a period separated list of at most three non-negative integers

Tags: app-store-connect

The upload to iTunes Connect fails both using Xcode and fastlane saying that my "CFBundleShortVersion" is 1.7.4.3 when that's clearly not the case from what I can tell.

These are the entries in the Info.plist:

[image]
[image]

Is there anywhere else that I should check? A week ago I uploaded 1.0 [Build 7] without any problems, it got rejected so i bumped the build number.

Comment: I checked the archived version and both Info.plist are correct and report the entries as 1.0 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

All the frameworks now need to do that as well, so you'll need to go to each target and set the "CFBundleShortVersion" to 1.0

LOL